# How can I output information from a different table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coldfusion

I have a query that i get the MAX number of "stars"

```
 <cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="getMaxstars">
SELECT   TOP (1) WITH TIES employee, SUM(execoffice_status) AS 'total_max'
FROM     CSEReduxResponses
GROUP BY employee
ORDER BY 'total_max' DESC
</cfquery >
```

I also have a different table EMPLOYEE. Table EMPLOYEE also comes from a different datasource="phonelist". Where in this table I have the employees first_name and last_name columns , they share the same column emp_id.
How can I output the employee first_name and last_name using the other table.

What I eventually I want to do it output:
max:
john doe - stars = 4

Comment: not really different question. This one uses two different columns.

Comment: @user3408399 you're joking, right? Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery like below:

```
select employee_id, sum(stars) as num_stars
  from table_a
 group by employee_id
having sum(stars) = (select max(num_stars)
                       from (select employee_id, sum(stars) as num_stars
                               from table_a
                              group by employee_id) x)
```

Comment: I know you are missing the GROUP BY , but in the end I get 'incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: I forgot the word "by"... one of those days. (both in the main query and the sub) Try with the edit.

Comment: did the changes but i still get 'Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ')'.'

Comment: @user3408399 it looks like sql server for some reason requires you to put an alias after the inline view. I just gave it an alias of x, see edit. It should eliminate that syntax error. Here is a demonstration of it running w/ example data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ff5eb/6/0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   TOP (1) WITH TIES employee_id, SUM(stars) AS 'total'
FROM     Table_A
GROUP BY employee_id
ORDER BY 'total' DESC
```

This is an alternative method.

Comment: "with ties" should probably be used if he were to use that method.

Comment: You are very correct sir.

Comment: @codyfail I use the code you gave me , but I have to change the question to not have two question asking the same thing.